# Is the product of primes less than $3\log_2{n}$ always at least $n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

Consider the product of all primes less than $3 \log_2{n}$.  Is it true that this product is always at least $n$ for all positive integers $n$?

> In general, what is the smallest $x_n$ so that the product of all
>   primes less than $x_n$ is always at least $n$?  Here $x_n$ is a function of
>   $n$.

I plotted $\frac{n}{\text{product of all primes less than $3 \log_2{n}$}}$ to support the conjecture.  Here it is for for $n$ from $2$ to $100$.

[image]

I computed the values for $n$ up to one million and the ratio gets smaller and smaller, supporting the conjecture.

I then repeated the same experiment but with $\frac{n}{\text{product of all primes less than $2 \log_2{n}$}}$.  Here it is for for $n$ from $3$ to $200$.

[image]

So it seems that the product of all primes less than $2 \log_2{n}$ might also work.

I also tried it with  $\frac{n}{\text{product of all primes less than $ \log_2{n}$}}$. The conjecture  no longer holds for small $n$ and it seems it might not even hold if you restrict it to large $n$.

Comment: If $n = 1$, $3 \log_2 n = 0$, it does not yield. You have to assume $n \geq 2$.

Comment: @Raito I believe the product of the empty set is $1$.

Comment: In any case, see [primorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial), specifically definition for natural numbers and asymptotics

Comment: @felipa That's a convention AFAIK, but you're right. It holds.

Comment: Did you look at the primorials as I suggested? All primes $\leq x$ are $\{p_1,p_2,p_{\pi(x)}\}$ so $\left \lfloor x  \right \rfloor \text{#}=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\pi(x)}p_k$ which is asymptotic to $e^{(1+o(1))\left \lfloor x  \right \rfloor }$ which is $\geq 2^{x}$ from some $x_0$ onwards. Replace $x$ with $2\log_2{n}$ and you are almost done.

Comment: @rtybase Is this asymptotic statement strong enough to answer the OP’s question which asks about all positive integers $n$?

Comment: From some finite $x_0$ onwards - yes, as I stated. All the other values between $0$ and $x_0$ can be verified with a computer.

Comment: @rtybase How can you compute what this $x_0$ is explicitly?

Comment: @felipa 1st by googling and checking [what was made on this subject so far](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.7208), page 20. Like, wikipedia link mentions Chebyshev function, because $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor \# = e^{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\pi(x)} \log{p_k}}=e^{\vartheta(x)}$. And then some individual attempts ... but the question is closed, I can't help.

Comment: ... like $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor \# =e^{\vartheta(x)}>e^{0.985x}$ from $x \geq 11927$ and $e^{0.985x}>2^x$ because $e^{0.985}=2.6778... > 2$.

Comment: @ThePhenotype Could you reopen the question please. I think it should be regarded as ok now and there is potentially an interesting answer.

Answer (score 3):

All primes $\leq x$ are $\{p_1,p_2,...,p_{\pi(x)}\}$ so (see [primorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial)) 
$$\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor \#=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{\pi(x)}p_k=e^{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\pi(x)}\ln{p_k}}=e^{\vartheta (x)}$$
According to [this paper, page 20](https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.7208)
$${\vartheta (x)>0.985x}, \forall x\geq 11927$$
and
$$e^{0.985}=2.6778...>2$$
Putting altogether
$$\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor \#=e^{\vartheta (x)}>e^{0.985x}>2^x, \forall x\geq 11927 \tag{1}$$
The first $11926$ cases can be checked with a computer, although some exceptions are easy to see:
$$2 < 2^2\\
2\cdot3 < 2^3\\
2\cdot3 < 2^4\\
2\cdot3\cdot5 < 2^5\\
2\cdot3\cdot5 < 2^6\\
\color{red}{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7 > 2^7}\\
2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7 < 2^8\\
2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7 < 2^9\\
2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7 < 2^{10}\\
\color{red}{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11 > 2^{11}}\\
2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11 < 2^{12}\\
\color{red}{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13 > 2^{13}}\\
\color{red}{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13 > 2^{14}}\\
2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13 < 2^{15}\\
2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13 < 2^{16}\\
\color{red}{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot17 > 2^{17}}$$

---

Let's find the exact minimal $x$ for which $(1)$ holds with this Python code:

```
import math

primes = []

def isPrime(n):
    l = int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1
    for i in range(2,l):
        if (n % i) == 0:
            return False
    return True

def primorial(n):
    result = 1
    i = 0
    while i < len(primes) and primes[i] <= n:
        result *= primes[i]
        i += 1
    return result

N = 11927

print("populate primes ...")
for i in range(2, N):
    if isPrime(i):
        primes.append(i);

for i in range(2, N):
    if (primorial(i) - 2**i < 0):
        print(i)
```

which prints

```
2
3
4
5
6
8
9
10
12
15
16
28
```

We can conclude $(1)$ is true for $\forall x > 28$.

---

Now taking $x=3\log_2⁡n$
$$\prod\limits_{p\leq 3\log_2⁡n}p > 2^{3\log_2⁡n}=n^3 \tag{2}$$
from $n_0 > 2^{\frac{28}{3}} \approx 813$ onwards.

Comment: This answer seems to suggest that we don’t need the 3 at all if we only look at $n$ greater than 11926. Will $\log_2 n$ really do?

Comment: @felipa I have updated the answer. Yes $x=\log_2 n$ will do from $n > 2^{28}$, which is quite big.

Answer (score 2):

**Here's an incomplete attempt** :

First, let be $\mathbb{P}$ the set of primes number and $\pi(n) = \textrm{card} \{ p \in \mathbb{P} \mid p \leq n \}$, then, by the profound theorem of primes number, $\pi(n) \sim \dfrac{n}{\ln n}$ when $n \to +\infty$.

At this point:

$\begin{align*}
A_n & = \prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}\atop p \leq 3\log_2 n} p \\
& \geq \prod_{p \in \mathbb{P} \atop p \leq 3 \log_2 n} 2 \\
& \geq 2^{\pi(3\log_2 n)}
\end{align*}$

Let be $a_n = 2^{\pi(3\log_2 n)}$ and $b_n = \ln(3\log_2 n) = \ln 3 - \ln \ln 10 + \ln \ln n \sim \ln \ln n \neq 0$ and $c_n = \dfrac{1}{b_n}$.

By the theorem of primes number, $2^{\pi(3\log_2 n)} \sim n^{3 c_n}$.

Now: $a_n = n^{3c_n} + o(n^{3 c_n})$.

With careful examination of $c_n = \dfrac{1}{\ln \ln n} + \ln \ln 10 - \ln 3 + o(1)$ when $n \to +\infty$, it should be possible to determine a lower bound of $c_n$, thus a lower bound of $a_n$, thus a lower bound of $A_n$.

The same work could be done on $x_n$, but will be much harder without precise inequalities, I believe.