# What's the sum of the inverses of the Primorial numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, infinite-product, primorial, chebyshev-function

> What's the sum of the inverses of the primorial numbers?

Let the $n^{th}$ primorial number be the product of the first $n$ primes

$\displaystyle n\#= \prod_{p\leq p_n}p$

So $N\#=2,2\cdot3,2\cdot3\cdot5,\ldots=2,6,30,210,\ldots$

Evaluate $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}\frac1{n\#}$

---

Here's what very limited part of this I can do:

Obviously it's in the fairly narrow interval $(\frac23,e-2)$ by comparing the first two terms and the sum of the inverses of all factorials.

We can look at the infinite product:

$1-\displaystyle\prod_n\left(1-\frac1{n\#}\right)$

And we have the rearrangement of the Chebyshev function to give:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n\#)^{1/p_n}=e$

Comment: By using Chebyshev function and its approximation [like here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665439/showing-prod-limits-p-leq-x-p-e1-epsilon-x-and-prod-limits-p-le/2665792#2665792), you can squeeze the sum to something looking like an infinite geometric progression sum

Comment: this is investigated somewhere at mathematical gazette.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numerical value is given with a precision of roughly 20,000 digits in http://oeis.org/A064648 .