# Prove that for every $ϵ>0$ there exist infinitely many natural numbers $n$, such that $τ(n)\geq 2^{(1-ϵ)(\log(n)/\log(\log(n))}$.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Prove that for every $ϵ>0$ there exist infinitely many natural numbers $n$, such that $$\tau(n)\geq 2^{(1-ϵ)\frac{\log(n)}{\log\log(n)}}$$

It is obvious to look at squarefree naturals of the form $n=p_1 p_2\cdots p_k$ where $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$ are first $k$ prime numbers. Such naturals have $\tau(n)=2^k$.

So I have to prove that for k large enough, $k>(1-ϵ)\frac{\log(n)}{\log(\log(n))}$.
I thought about putting exp on both sides so we have to prove 
$\exp(k)>n^{\frac{1-ϵ}{\log(\log(n))}}$.

There must be a chain of inequalities starting from $n^{\frac{1-ϵ}{\log(\log(n))}}<\cdots<\cdots<\cdots<\exp(k)$. I was trying to do it yesterday but my inequalities were tnot proper. Of course I can write "$1$" instead of "$1-ϵ$" or write $\log(\log(2))$ or $\log(\log(p_k))$ instead of $\log(\log(n))$ in denominator but that directs me to nothing. Later all I can do with $n$ is saying that $n<p_k^k$ but this is too strong - because this side will be bigger than $\exp(k)$.

Any hints?

Comment: @Gary, You edited my question badly. log(n)/log(log(n)) is multiplied by (1-epsilon) in power of two. It is not ike you edited.

Comment: Sorry, but it looked more like that from your original post. Btw, what is $\tau$?

Comment: @Gary tau is the number of positive divisord of n.

Comment: *Hint:* ${\displaystyle \tau(p_{k})=2}<2^{(1-\varepsilon)\frac{\log{p_k}}{\log{\log{p_k}}}} \iff
\frac{1}{1-\varepsilon}<\frac{\log{p_k}}{\log{\log{p_k}}}$ for large enough primes $p_k$, since $\frac{x}{\log{x}}$ is ascending for $x\geq 3$.

Comment: @rtybase ok, I see where I made a mistake. My numbers need to be squarefree numbers but no starting form 2,3,5... but all prime divisors must be large enough so holds what You wrote. Now I know what to write :)

Comment: @rtybase no, Im not right at that moment. I have to also prove that log(n)/log(log(n)) is < sum from 1 to k log(pk)/log(log(pk).

Comment: @rtybase that Gary changed the quality badly during edit. t should be >= not <=..

Comment: Are you trying to prove [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Severin_Wigert)?

Comment: @rtybase i think we can say so.

Comment: What do you think about the 2nd part of the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Wigert's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Severin_Wigert) result
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log \tau(n)}{\log n/\log\log n}=\log2 \Rightarrow \\
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log \tau(n)}{\log2 \cdot \log n/\log\log n}=1 \Rightarrow \\
\exists n \text{ s.t. } \frac{\log \tau(n)}{\log2 \cdot \log n/\log\log n}> 1-\varepsilon \Rightarrow \\
\tau(n)>2^{(1-\varepsilon)\frac{\log{n}}{\log{\log{n}}}}$$

---

Or use [Chebyshev function and the fact that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665439/showing-prod-limits-p-leq-x-p-e1-epsilon-x-and-prod-limits-p-le/) $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists x(\varepsilon)>0$ s.t. $\forall x > x(\varepsilon)$
$$e^{(1-\varepsilon)x}<\prod\limits_{p\leq x}p< e^{(1+\varepsilon)x} \Rightarrow $$
$$(1-\varepsilon)x<\log{\prod\limits_{p\leq x}p}< (1+\varepsilon)x \Rightarrow 
\color{blue}{x > \frac{\log{\prod\limits_{p\leq x}p}}{1+\varepsilon}} \tag{1}$$
Use [PNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) or [better](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206815/is-there-a-way-to-show-that-sqrtp-n-n) $$\color{blue}{\pi(x)>\frac{x}{\log{x}}} \tag{2}$$
Note that $\frac{x}{\log{x}}$ is **ascending** for large enough $x$'s:
$$\frac{x}{\log{x}}\overset{\color{red}{(1)}}{>} \frac{\frac{\log{\prod\limits_{p\leq x}p}}{1+\varepsilon}}{\log{\frac{\log{\prod\limits_{p\leq x}p}}{1+\varepsilon}}}\tag{3}$$

Then, by noting $n_x=\prod\limits_{p\leq x}p$ and considering that $2^x$ is ascending:
$$\tau(n_x)=\tau\left(\prod\limits_{p\leq x}p\right)= 
2^{\pi(x)}\overset{\color{red}{(2)}}{>}
2^{\frac{x}{\log{x}}} \overset{\color{red}{(3)}}{>} \\
2^{\frac{1}{1+\varepsilon}\frac{\log{\prod\limits_{p\leq x}p}}{\log{\left(\log{\prod\limits_{p\leq x}p}\right)-\log{(1+\varepsilon)}}}}=
2^{\frac{1}{1+\varepsilon}\frac{\log{n_x}}{\log{\log{n_x}}-\log{(1+\varepsilon)}}}> 
2^{(1-\varepsilon)\frac{\log{n_x}}{\log{\log{n_x}}}}$$
because $1>1-\varepsilon^2=(1+\varepsilon)(1-\varepsilon) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1+\varepsilon}>1-\varepsilon$. We can build an infinite sequence of such $n_x$'s.