# How can we prove $\sum_{p\leq x}\ln(p) < 2x$?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, chebyshev-function

I've been reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504289.pdf) for Merten's second theorem. Every thing is just fine but I think that theorem 11 (3.5.2) can have an easier proof.
Is there any better approach or an explanation that why that $\ln([x]!)$ can be written in the form of those thetas.

Comment: You can also use some insights from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665439/showing-prod-limits-p-leq-x-p-e1-epsilon-x-and-prod-limits-p-le/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was well-known that the divisor sum of von Mangoldt function $\Lambda(n)=[n=p^k]\log p$ is logarithm:
$$
\sum_{d|n}\Lambda(d)=\log n
$$

Using identities of logarithm, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\log\lfloor x\rfloor!
&=\sum_{n\le x}\log n=\sum_{n\le x}\sum_{d|n}\Lambda(d) \\
&=\sum_{qd\le x}\Lambda(q)=\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)\sum_{m\le x/n}1 \\
&=\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)\left\lfloor\frac xn\right\rfloor
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, if we gather all the prime powers, then
$$
\log\lfloor x\rfloor!=\sum_{p\le x}\left(\sum_{k\ge1}\left\lfloor x\over p^k\right\rfloor\right)\log p
$$
By exchanging summation order, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\log\lfloor x\rfloor!
&=\sum_{k\ge1}\sum_{p\le x}\left\lfloor x\over p^k\right\rfloor\log p=\sum_{k\ge1}\sum_{p\le x}\sum_{m\le x/p^k}\log p \\
&=\sum_{mp^k\le x}\log p=\sum_{m,k\ge1}\sum_{p\le\sqrt[k]{x/m}}\log p \\
&=\sum_{m,k\ge1}\vartheta\left(\sqrt[k]\frac xm\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\vartheta(x)=\sum_{p\le x}\log p$.

Comment: Seems like that your first line has a little problem.There should $d$ as the input of the Mangoldt function. Can I you please correct it so others can go through reading it more confidently ?

Comment: @ParsaNoori Edited. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You're welcome. Forgot to say that it's on the second mathematical line too.

Comment: @ParsaNoori Edited again, thanks for that one :D